# How to create qooxdoo ruler widget?

Tags: qooxdoo

What will be the most efficent way to create ruler widget: rectangle area with scale (graphical vertical lines with numbers) which can be scrolled left/right?
Should I use some layout and add atom widgets with icon (one pixel width vertical line image) and number as text label?
Or maybe use simple widgets with black background and width of 1 pixel?

Answer (score 1):

As Tobi said, using widgets for possibly hundreds of graphic primitives (tick marks, labels etc.) is wasteful. SVG is made for programmatically creating graphics.

Most relevant for a ruler are the pattern rules:

`<pattern id="5pxTickMarks" width="5px" height="100%" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <line stroke="#999" stroke-width="1px" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="50%"/>
</pattern>`

That's a horizontally repeating pattern with a width of 5px which draws a vertical line (every 5px) in a subdued grey and 50% height. This pattern alone doesn't actually draw anything: after setting it up you use it to 'paint' the relevant area:

```
<rect fill="url(#5pxTickMarks)" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%"/>
```

That draws a rectangle over the whole canvas filled with pattern referenced in `fill`. Repeat for the other features...

I just did a SVG ruler (for html), it's a bit more complete and could be a starting point: [SVG Ruler](https://matthi.coffee/2016/i-rule-dot-svg)

Answer (score 0):

I would create the ruler markings in svg (or canvas if must be). Using individual qx widgets placed on a qx canvas seem a rather heavy handed approach to me.